# How to preserve setTimeout parameter value until execution?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a bit of code that executes on keypress and saves data to a database as the user types.

I added a setTimeout function with a clearTimeout infront of it so not EVERY single character the user enters is sending out an Ajax request to save data.

While the setTimeout works great for one input field , if the user decides to switch input fields quickly (before the setTimeout delay is up) the parameter passed to the callSomeAjax changes before the function is executed.

Simplified version of what's happening...

```
var a = 1; //some user data

//function to call ajax script to save data to database
function callSomeAjax(a)
{
   console.log(a);
}

setTimeout(function(){callSomeAjax(a)},1000); //executes callSomeAjax after 1 second delay

a=3; //change user data before callSomeAjax executes

// Result of console.log is 3, not 1 like I want it to be...
```

[Code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U59Hv/)

Any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to do individual ajax updates for each input field, or does 1 ajax call save the entire form to the DB?

Comment: Don't use a global setTimeout, simply create one once the user starts typing, in the scope of the input that the user is typing in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `setTimeout` doesn't run the function passed in until 1 second has passed.  What that does happen `a` has changed, so when `callSomeAjax(a)` is ran, `a` is at its new value.

You need to capture (in a closure) the value of `a` before calling `setTimeout`.

```
var a = 1;

function show(a) {
    console.log(a);
}

(function(a){
    setTimeout(function () {
        show(a)
    }, 1000);
}(a));

a = 3;
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/U59Hv/2/

Comment: This solution works great but I'd like to understand what you're doing here. I get the basic concept of closures... a closure is a function inside a function. The inside or child function can access variables from the parent function.... but what is happening when you put (a) in parentheses on the line before a = 3?

Comment: What is happening is that I am creating a function `function(a){}`, and then I am immediately calling it `(function(a){}(a))`.  This calls my anonymous function and passes it `a` as a parameter.  It's called an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).  This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 9):

Newer browsers will let you pass the argument to `setTimeout`, and retrieve it in the callback.

```
setTimeout(function(a){
    return callSomeAjax(a);
}, 1000, a);
```

---

Or you could bind it to the function

```
setTimeout(function(a){
    return callSomeAjax(a);
}.bind(null, a), 1000);
```

---

Aside from those, you'd need to create the `setTimeout` callback in a new scope with the value.

```
function callbackWithValue(a) {
    return function() {
        return callSomeAjax(a);
    };
}

setTimeout(callbackWithValue(a), 1000);
```

---

Or if you already have the function as you do, and there's nothing else to pass, then you can make it more generic...

```
function callbackWithValue(fn) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(null, args);
    };
}

setTimeout(callbackWithValue(callSomeAjax, a), 1000);
```

This last one is shows the beginnings of a `.bind()` function. It can be further expanded to allow the binding of `this` and the concatenation of additional arguments passed after the bound one.

Answer (score 0):

This works and can be also used within loop.

```js
var x = "OK";
setTimeout(alertOK.bind(null,x), 3000);
x = "Would be WRONG";
console.log("before timeout:", x);

function alertOK(x){
 console.log("after timeout:",x);
}
```

It might not be better answer than the accepted one, just different idea. Since function is not created, it can also be used in loops.
In my opinion, code is a bit more readable this way.

Comment: Could you add a little information about how this works and why this is better than the existing (and accepted) answers?

Comment: @DaleMyers: it might not be better than existing, just another approach and simpler code, IMO.